# SQL Server, how can I transpose data of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

I have a query

```
SELECT city FROM cityTable
```

it returns

```
delhi
faridabad
haryana
mathura
kerla
```

I just want result in transpose manner something like

```
delhi | faridabad | haryana | mathura | kera
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Assuming these are supposed to be columns, what should the values in the rows be? Nulls?

Comment: Take a look at [Pivots with dynamic columns](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STUFF (
 (SELECT N', ' + city FROM CityTable FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
```

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Thanks sir, But i want just transpose of a column result.
I mean, result should return in single Row and with separate column.
Is it possible???

Comment: This shows how to write a comma separated list, but what if the desired result is a table with many columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @city nvarchar(max)
SELECT @city = coalesce(@city+' | ', '')+city FROM cityTable
```

EDIT:

In order to show the result

```
SELECT @city
```

Comment: It is not returning result....

Comment: @RakeshHolkar - you have to select variable city after the operation as in my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` as the example posted on here

[TSQL – Transpose Data using Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/20/tsql-transpose-data-using-using-pivot-and-unpivot/)

NOTE: You can find the syntax on BOL (books on line) of SQL